# How do I wipe and reset my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, reset

How do I reset my Ubuntu, and wipe the hard drive in the process? I'm completely new to Ubuntu, so please no terminal commands and such.

Answer (score 0):

Make a LiveUSB with a Ubuntu image from ubuntu.com using e.g. LinuxLive USB Creator - www.linuxliveusb.com/

Then boot from USB, and choose install Ubuntu. In the installation progress you have the option to securely erase your hard drive first(although it's seldom necessary, especially with SSD's)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Download a Ubuntu .iso and write it to a CD or DVD, or use LinuxLive. Using a disc can be more strait forward.
Get an ethernet cable, not all wifi cards are supported out of the box. The cable can be used to get the drivers.
Back up important user data first on a usb.
Use live image and do a full install. For secure deletion of data, Bleach bit or similar can be installed to erase free space.